# Unable to restore SQL Server database - 'The file or filegroup <logfilename> cannot be selected for this operation.'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

When restoring a full DB backup to a different SQL Server 2005 Express server, I receive the following message:

> The file or filegroup "mydatabase_log"
>   cannot be selected for this operation.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server,
>   Error: 3219)

I've checked the restore options to make sure that filenames are valid locations for it to restore to.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed it by using Restore Database instead of Restore Files

Answer (score 0):

You have checked the 'Force Restore' box in the options?